# Join two fields from one table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have two table as follows

Table1

```
id   name   appid  modifiedappid
---  ---    ----   ------------
1    abc     1        2
```

Table2

```
id   apllicationName
--   ---------------
1       App1
2       App2
```

when join these two table i need the below result

```
Name   appname   Modifiedappname
-----  -------   ----------------
abc     app1      app2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to Join `Table2` twice

```
select Name , 
       B.apllicationName as appname,
       C.apllicationName as Modifiedappname
from Table1 A
Left join Table2 B on A.appid  = B.id
Left join Table2 C on A.modifiedappid = C.id
```

**Note :** If the values of `appid` &  `modifiedappid` in `Table1` will always have entry in `Table2` then you can change the`Left Outer Join` to `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Can we make it in a single Join?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select t1.Name, t2.ApplicationName as appname, t3.ApplicationName as modifiedappname from Table1 t1
Left Outer Join Table2 t2
on t2.id= t1.id
Left outer Join Table2 t3
on t3.id=t1.id
group by t1.Name, t2.ApplicationName, t3.ApplicationName
```

Comment: Can we make it in a single Join?